How to access old Gmail account?
I no longer have the phone number associated with account but I know the email and password I've done all the things asked but because i have the phone number associated with it and i can't access the secondary email account

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
